# Access my VS2013 internet application via the internet

Tags: c#, browser, localhost, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-express

I have created a C# MVC 5 Internet Application, that I can access via the localhost address in my web browser. As my computer is connected to the internet (via a router), is it possible to connect to my internet application from another computer other than my development computer?

What address do I need to use? Do I need to change any windows settings to do this?

Can I please have some help with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1)Run Visual Studios in administrator mode

2)Changed the binding protocols and allow for incoming directions as suggested http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer

-But after that, I have a service unavailable (503) error

3)So I followed this : IIS Express Enable External Request - 503 Added just the port protocol and port:ip protocol,

```
<bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":1904:" />
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":1904:10.1.10.123" />
</bindings>
```

Also here there's another article about this:http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer